# is it possible to send an action request to a mobile phone?

Tags: android, ios, request

So I have an AWS EC2 instance.

When ROUTE_1 receives a request from a mobile phone, I want the RESPONSE to the mobile phone to achieve three things in sequence.

1. Open the camera, wait for the user to take a photo
2. Ask the user to enter one input field
3. On submit send input data and photos to ROUTE_2 specified in RESPONSE

**The Question is:**

Is it possible to send 'action-requests' like this?

*or*

would it be easier to send them to a webpage with the above-mentioned functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called a form element silly :P

Route_1 returns a form element for the user to fill out and submit to route_2

Example:

```html
<form id="mf" action="https://example.com/route_1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="thing to enter" type="text" name="thing1" required />
    <label id=image1_lab for="image1">Take selfie
        <input type="file" style="display:none" id="image1" name="image1" accept="image/*" capture="user"
            required>
    </label>
    <button id="submit">
        <span> submit</span>
    </button>
</form>
```